# Maven failure to find artifact cached in <repoAddress> was cached in the local repository

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, artifactory, dependency-management

I have a maven artifact in Artifactory. I am trying to refer that in one of my projects in Maven. I have the dependency element put as shown below.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.ci.servicemanager</groupId>
   <artifactId>ci-service-manager</artifactId>
   <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

But its failing with the below shown error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project integration-tests: Could not resolve dependencies for project intelligence:integration-tests:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.ci.servicemanager:ci-service-manager:all-jar:8126251 in https://artifactory.mkn.ci.cloud/artifactory/CI-Release-Local was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of CI-Release-Local has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

When I got to my local repo, I can see the download artifacts in the shown way.

```
csv2980:8126251 mmacilamany$ ls -al
total 48
drwxr-xr-x  8 mmacilamany  admin  256 Apr 30 15:48 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 mmacilamany  admin  192 Apr 30 15:33 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 mmacilamany  admin  183 Apr 30 15:33 _remote.repositories
-rw-r--r--  1 mmacilamany  admin  297 Apr 30 15:48 ci-service-manager-8126251.all-.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 mmacilamany  admin  297 Apr 30 15:48 ci-service-manager-8126251.all-jar.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 mmacilamany  admin  297 Apr 30 15:33 ci-service-manager-8126251.jar.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--  1 mmacilamany  staff  461 Apr 30 15:33 ci-service-manager-8126251.pom
-rw-r--r--  1 mmacilamany  staff   40 Apr 30 15:33 ci-service-manager-8126251.pom.sha1
```

Though the jars are getting downloaded, why am I getting error? I tried deleting the local repo artifacts and trying again. Still no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: When I delete the local repo, maven is trying to download from this url, Downloading: https://artifactory.mkn.ci.cloud/artifactory/CI-Release-Local/com/ci/servicemanager/ci-service-manager/8126251/ci-service-manager-8126251.jar.
but the actual downloadable URL looks like.

https://artifactory.mkn.ci.cloud/artifactory/CI-Release-Local/com/ci/servicemanager/ci-service-manager/8126251/ci-service-manager-8126251-all.jar

Difference is an additional "-all.jar" in the actual uploaded file's name. How can I handle this situation.

Comment: You should give a correct version and `LATEST` is not really a valid version nor should it be used...furthermore the type is simply wrong...

Comment: I edited the question, please check once more :) I believe "LATEST" is the way to get the latest version downloaded all the time, and it actually is getting the latest version number when its trying to download as you can see in the download url.

Comment: In this case I would say the version is `8126251` and the `all` is a so called classifier which needs to given as `<classifier>all</classifier>` if you like to use only that artifact...

Comment: yes that solved it. Please put it as answer. I'll accept it.